# CRUD with AngularJS and Slim PHP 404 not found

Tags: angularjs, rest, get, http-status-code-404, slim

I am familiarizing with `RESTful` api (`CRUD`) with `AngularJS` and `Slim PHP` framework. I am following this tutorial : http://www.blog.iamaronbarbosa.com/building-a-basic-crud-application-using-angularjs-and-slim-php-framework-part-1/ . And when the application tried to `GET` data (file: `angular-crud/slim/index.php`),

```
function ListCtrl($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('api/users').success(function(data) {
        $scope.users = data;
    });
}
```

I get the error code stating,

`Status Code:    HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found`

The url to GET the data is : `http://localhost/angular-crud/slim/api/users`.

**EDIT**

HOWEVER, if I apply the url as `http://localhost/angular-crud/slim/api/index.php/users` it returns the data fine. Is it a must to inlude the `index.php`? if not is there a workaround to retrieve data using with the url `http://localhost/angular-crud/slim/api/users` ?

I am very new to this area and I apologize if the question  is vague. I tried checking the ports and ran tests using `RESTClient` but ended up empty handed. You expert advice on this matter is highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The need to route via `index.php` is indicative of an issue with URL rewriting.  From the documentation:

> Slim will work without URL rewriting. In this scenario, you must
>   include the name of the PHP file in which you instantiate and run the
>   Slim application in the resource URI.

Please see the "[Route URL Rewriting](http://docs.slimframework.com/#Route-URL-Rewriting)" section of the Slim documentation for details on how to properly route URL's in both Apache and nginx.

Comment: Thank you sir for the answer. It was a rewrite issue :)

Answer (score 1):

I imaginge that the there must be a .htaccess file in your project that rewrites the url from http:// localhost/angular-crud/slim/api/users to http:// localhost/angular-crud/slim/api/index.php/users. Check if your localhost allows .htaccess overrides

Comment: TThank you very much sir i will check on this